# RegEx for adding a char in specific places

Tags: python, regex, javadoc, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to analyze Javadoc comments in python and for that, I need full stops for splitting. How can I add full stops in the right places in a Javadoc comment?

I want something like this:
Input:

```
/**
     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if
     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true
     * is returned
     *
     * @param vertex
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException.
     *
     * @return b
     */
```

Output:

```
/**
     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if
     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true
     * is returned.*here*
     *
     * @param vertex.*here*
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException.*here*
     *
     * @return b.*here*
     */
```

Note: If a full stop/semicolon/comma already exists, then replacement is not required since my program splits on the basis of these 3 punctuation marks.

In addition, Javadoc descriptions can have inline tags, like {@link...}, no punctuation marks are required around this.

**Only before @param, @throw, @return(at the end as well) is required.**

SOLUTION

```
test_str = ("/**\n"
    "     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if\n"
    "     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true\n"
    "     * is returned\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @param vertex\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @throws NullPointerException.\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @return b\n"
    "     */")

result = re.sub(r'(@param|@throw|@return)', r'.\1', test_str)
print(result)
```

This adds a full stop in the places required except for after the last tag, not a problem for splitting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those with missing `.`, you can simply write an expression maybe similar to:

```
(\* @param|@return)(.*)
```

which you can replace it with `$1$2.`

[image]

#### RegEx

You can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mPyrfU/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(\* @param|@return)(.*)/gm;
const str = `/**
     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if
     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true
     * is returned
     *
     * @param vertex
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException.
     *
     * @return b
     */`;
const subst = `$1$2.`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\* @param|@return)(.*)"

test_str = ("/**\n"
    "     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if\n"
    "     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true\n"
    "     * is returned\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @param vertex\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @throws NullPointerException.\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @return b\n"
    "     */")

subst = "\\1\\2."

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
/**
     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if
     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true
     * is returned
     *
     * @param vertex.
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException.
     *
     * @return b.
     */
```

#### Expression for description

If you like to add a `.` after description, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/0i8ple/1) might work:

```
([\s\*]+@param)
```

#### Python Code

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([\s\*]+@param)"

test_str = ("/**\n"
    "     * The addVertex method checks to see if the vertex isn't null, and then if\n"
    "     * the graph does not contain the vertex, the vertex is then added and true\n"
    "     * is returned\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @param vertex\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @throws NullPointerException.\n"
    "     *\n"
    "     * @return b\n"
    "     */")

subst = ".\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Hi! The one with the dot was to show that it doesn't need to be replaced if there is already a dot, semi-colon or comma. Also, I would need a dot before the @param tag, the ending of the description. I would really appreciate if you could provide me with python code, I am extremely sorry for not specifying the programming language I am using. Updated it now! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Emma. It does work. Any idea on how I could add a dot before the @param tag? I mean after the description lines. Thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly but it is in my current question though. Just that a javadoc comment structure looks like the same example. 
/** blah blah blah blah
*blah blah blah
*blah blah blah.
* @ param blah.
* @ throws blah.
* @ return blah.
*/
I can only post again after a few hours, so...but I appreciate the effort!

Comment: The '@param' disappears from the result. But the former code did the job(almost). Thanks again! I found another solution that works for me. Will update it.